# Extending a contour in OpenCv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

i have several contours that consist of several black regions in my image. Directly adjacent to these black regions are some brighter regions that do not belong to my contours. I want to add these brighter regions to my black region and therefor extend my contour in OpenCv.
Is there a convenient way to extend a contour? I thought about looking at intensity change from my gradient-image created with `cv::Sobel` and extend until the gradient changes again, meaning the intensity of pixel is going back to the neither black nor bright regions of the image.

Thanks!

Here are example images. The first picture shows the raw Image, the second the extracted Contour using Canny & findContours, the last one the Sobel-Gradient intensity Image of the same area.
I want to include the bright boundaries in the first image to the Contour.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Update: Now i've used some morphological operations on the Sobelgradients and added a contour around them (see Image below). Next step could be to find the adjacent pair of purple & red contours, but it seems very much like a waste of procession time to actually have to search for directly adjacent contours. Any better ideas?

[image]

Update 2: My solution for now is to search for morphed gradient (red) contours in a bounding box around my (purple) contours and pick the one with correct orientation & size. This works for gradient contours where the morphological operation closes the "rise" and "fall" gradient areas like in Figure 3. But it is still a bad solution for cases in which the lighted area is wider then in the image above. Any idea is still very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample image !!!

Comment: Okay, added some pictures and clarification to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is find two different features and merge them.  It's not terribly difficult but you have to use multiple copies of the image to make it happen.

1. Make one copy, and threshold it for the dark portion
2. Make another copy and threshold it for the light portion
3. Merge both thresholded images into a new image
4. Apply a morphological operation like opening or closing (depending on how you threshold)  This will connect nearby components
5. Find contours in the resultant image
6. Use those contours on your original image.  This will work since all the images are the same size and all based off of the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, the approach mentioned in the original post wasn't very useful because it could not handle large light regions. Your approach is roughly what i have come up with too in the end and it works just fine. But my approach was to find dark portion, then lay a ROI around it and search in the light-portion-image for the one best fitting partner, then merge them. Your approach may fail if i got several light portions around a dark portion.

Comment: Nevertheless i will accept your answer because the approach of thresholding the image two times led to my final solution...

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I didn't realize that you might have multiple light portion candidates of which you need to pick the best one.  Glad I could be of assistance.